# Can you tell me why this alert does not work?

Tags: javascript

Can you tell me why this alert does not work?

my js codes:

```
var character =
document.getElementById("character");
var block = document.getElementById("block");




function jump() {
if (character.classList != "animate") {
    character.classList.add("animate");
}

setTimeout(function () {
    character.classList.remove("animate");
}, 500);

var checkDead = setlnterval(function () {
    var characterTop =
        parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(character)
            .getPropertyValue("top"));

    var blockLeft =
        parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(block)
            .getPropertyValue("left"));
```

here is the if part (my problem): i want to know why it dose not work?

```
        if (blockLeft<20 && blockLeft>0 && characterTop>=130) {
        block.style.animation = "none";
        block.style.display = "none";
        alert("U Lose!");
    }
}, 10);
```

}

Comment: Try logging the variables to see if they meet the conditions.

Comment: `character.classList != "animate"` will always be true. Use `!character.classList.includes("animate")`

Comment: But there's no need for that condition at all. Adding to a classList doesn't do anything if the class is already there. So just do it unconditionally.

Comment: Also, fyi: `parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(block).getPropertyValue("left"));` can be written just as: `parseInt(getComputedStyle(block).left, 10);` (you should always pass [the optional second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to `parseInt`, which is the radix.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -3):

If there will be two alert boxes when you run the code, then check the "prevent this page from creating additional dialog" checkbox. Refresh the page again and you won't get the alert box ever again.

Solution is that you need to **close that webpage and reopen it again in the browser** (don't need to close the entire browser). I am assuming you are using **Chrome**. Internet Explorer or Firefox don't have this checkbox feature.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and it's nice that you try to contribute right away!
Unfortunately it's not a good answer though. The problem here isn't that there comes unwanted alerts, but the problem is that the alert doesn't work for some reason (probably simply related to the values of the variables).